# getting error like relation "_unknown" does not exist?

Tags: odoo

I have created one model, It contain 2 fields and one grid view. So I am trying to many2one for one field to create new id. Please let me know where i am making the mistake ?

.py code is here

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class agile_portfolio(osv.Model):
    _name = "agile.portfolio"
    _rec_name = 'epic_owner'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Asset Name',),
        'epic_owner':fields.many2one('Agile.assetid.name','Asset ID'),



        'strat_id1' : fields.one2many('portfolio.grid','strat_id','Strategy Name'),
    }
agile_portfolio()

class portfolio_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'portfolio.grid'
    _columns = { 
                'name' : fields.char('Part'),

                'strat_code' : fields.char('Code'),
                'strat_quty' : fields.char('Quantity '),
                'strat_uom' : fields.char('UoM'),
                'strat_id': fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Strat Id'),
            }

portfolio_grid()

class assetid_name(osv.Model):
    _name = 'assetid.name'
    _rec_name = 'asst_id'
    _columns = {
        'asst_id' : fields.char('Asset_ID'),
    }
assetid_name()
```

**.xml code is  here**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>
        <!--Portfolio View-->
            <record id="agile_portfolio_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">agile.portfolio.form</field>
            <field name="model">agile.portfolio</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="AssetConfig">
                    <group>
                        <group>
                        <field name="name"/>

                        </group>
                                    <group>
                            <field name="epic_owner"/>

                        </group>
                    </group>        
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Part Name">
                        <field name="strat_id1">
                            <form string="Part Name">
                                <group>
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="strat_code"/>
                                <field name="strat_quty"/>
                                <field name="strat_uom"/>
                                </group>
                            </form>
                            <tree string="Part Name">
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="strat_code"/>
                                <field name="strat_quty"/>
                                <field name="strat_uom"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
                </form>
            </field>    
        </record>
        <record id="agile_portfolio_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">AssetConfigs</field>
            <field name="res_model">agile.portfolio</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>    
            <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click to create a new portfolio</p>
            </field>    
            </record>



        <!--side menu's-->

        <menuitem id="asset_config" name="AssetConfigs"/>
        <menuitem id="portfolio_menu" name="AssetParts" parent="asset_config"/>
        <menuitem id="portfolio_nxt_menu" name="AssetParts" parent="portfolio_menu" action="agile_portfolio_action"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

***openerp*.py**

```
{
'name': 'Agile',
'version':'1.0',
'description': """
    Agile Methodology
    - Portfolios
    - Programs
    - Projects
""",
'author': 'Suraj',
'depends': ['base_setup',],
'data': ['agile_view.xml',],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given the wrong model name in following field.

```
'epic_owner':fields.many2one('Agile.assetid.name','Asset ID')
```

Here instead of **"Agile.assetid.name"** you have to give **"assetid.name"** if you want to manage M2O of last model **"assetid.name"**. I think no model have capital letter.

I think this will resolve your issue.

Comment: i am not able add many2one field in asset inheritance  i want asset.name names visible to asset part . i done like 'name':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Asset name') and added in xml and open erp file but its shovin 500 server error please help me out

Comment: Please do not make confuse. Write down all your classed in your question. It is very helpful to resolve this.

Comment: from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class asset_attach(osv.osv):
 _inherit = "asset.asset"
 #_rec_name = 'paname'

 _columns = {
  'assetname1' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Asset_IDS'),}

Comment: <record id="asset_assets_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">asset.asset.form</field>
   <field name="model">asset.asset</field>
   
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="asset.assets_form_view"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="user_id" position="after">
     
     <field name="assetname1"/>
     
     
    </field>
   </field>
  </record>

Comment: {
 'name': 'Asset Edit',
 'version':'1.0',
 'description': """
  Asset Edit
  - Epics
  - Grid or Tree view as template
 """,
 'author': 'Shridhar',
 'depends': ['base_setup','asset','Agile'],
 'data': ['hredit_attach_view.xml',],
 'installable': True,
 'auto_install': False,
}

Comment: this 3 are .py,.xml,openerp file am getting error at assetname1 field

Comment: First of all just make change as I have write down in my answer. Then after restart your OpenERP server and upgrade your module.